Azure function app (python) Retry with timer_trigger is not working
I am facing an issue to run the below code. I directly ran the code from the Microsoft official documentation
from azure.functions import FunctionApp, TimerRequest, Context, AuthLevel
import logging

app = FunctionApp(http_auth_level=AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


@app.timer_trigger(schedule="*/1 * * * * *", arg_name="mytimer",
                   run_on_startup=False,
                   use_monitor=False)
@app.retry(strategy="fixed_delay", max_retry_count="3",
           delay_interval="00:00:01")
def mytimer(mytimer: TimerRequest, context: Context) -> None:
    logging.info(f'Current retry count: {context.retry_context.retry_count}')

    if context.retry_context.retry_count == \
            context.retry_context.max_retry_count:
        logging.info(
            f"Max retries of {context.retry_context.max_retry_count} for "
            f"function {context.function_name} has been reached")
    else:
        raise Exception("This is a retryable exception")

I am getting this error:
Received WorkerMetadataRequest, request ID b7bfaf90-17e3-4983-b4a5-1ce251db2312, directory: /src/components/test
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z] Worker failed to index functions
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z] Result: Failure
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z] Exception: AttributeError: 'FunctionApp' object has no attribute 'retry'
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z] Stack:   File "/usr/lib/azure-functions-core-tools-4/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 338, in handle_functions_metadata_request
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z]     fx_metadata_results = self.index_functions(function_path)
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z]   File "/usr/lib/azure-functions-core-tools-4/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 607, in index_functions
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.466Z]     indexed_functions = loader.index_function_app(function_path)
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]   File "/usr/lib/azure-functions-core-tools-4/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]   File "/usr/lib/azure-functions-core-tools-4/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 151, in index_function_app
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]     imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.467Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]   File "/src/components/test/function_app.py", line 10, in <module>
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z]     @app.retry(strategy="fixed_delay", max_retry_count="3",
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.468Z] .
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.473Z] 0 functions found
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.491Z] 0 functions loaded
[2024-06-05T03:09:22.493Z] Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle at /home/vscode/.azure-functions-core-tools/Functions/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle

I am using poetry, azure function apps and docker container with the following package versions:

python 3.10
azure-functions 1.19.0
azure-core 1.30.1
azure-identity 1.16.0
Python model v2 in Azure
run time version on azure: 4.34.1.1

I did try with azure function 1.19.0; the retry policy is there for timertrigger but I am still getting this annoying issue.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/blob/bdeb2c2e29dd491129784ccb5cf5b5371b1ce286/azure/functions/decorators/function_app.py#L3190
EDIT:
Folder Structure

Steps to run

Docker image FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10-core-tools
Docker build and docker exec -it bash
cd to folder structure
poetry config virtual env true
poetry shell
poetry install
func host start --python --verbose



Make sure, you have created a V2 model python Azure function. If so, then your folder structure should look like below.



You should have given codes in the below mentioned files.

function_app.py-
import logging
from azure.functions import FunctionApp, TimerRequest, Context, AuthLevel

app = FunctionApp(http_auth_level=AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="*/1 * * * * *", arg_name="mytimer", run_on_startup=False,
              use_monitor=False) 
@app.retry(strategy="fixed_delay", max_retry_count="3",
           delay_interval="00:00:01")
def mytimer(mytimer: TimerRequest, context: Context) -> None:
    logging.info(f'Current retry count: {context.retry_context.retry_count}')

    if context.retry_context.retry_count == \
            context.retry_context.max_retry_count:
        logging.info(
            f"Max retries of {context.retry_context.max_retry_count} for "
            f"function {context.function_name} has been reached")
    else:
        raise Exception("This is a retryable exception")

host.json-
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

local.settings.json-
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

requirements.txt-
azure-functions

If you have all these codes in your folder structure then you will be able to get the expected response alike me.
Enable Azurite (fn + f5) before executing the function.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc8*****7bdd (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572


Functions:

        mytimer: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-05T07:18:08.035Z] Executing 'Functions.mytimer' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-06-05T12:48:08.0148226+05:30', Id=c5512c8b-4abd-41e3-9871-f7b5d574e060)
[2024-06-05T07:18:08.095Z] Current retry count: 0
[2024-06-05T07:18:08.134Z] Executed 'Functions.mytimer' (Failed, Id=c5512c8b-4abd-41e3-9871-f7b5d574e060, Duration=108ms)
[2024-06-05T07:18:08.136Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.mytimer. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: Exception: This is a retryable exception
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 545, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 826, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\functionApp\78578594\function_app.py", line 19, in mytimer
    raise Exception("This is a retryable exception")
.
[2024-06-05T07:18:09.167Z] Executing 'Functions.mytimer' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-06-05T12:48:09.1667627+05:30', Id=fc680c7a-cd73-4d7c-9976-ed3facc8c591)
[2024-06-05T07:18:09.176Z] Current retry count: 1
[2024-06-05T07:18:09.178Z] Executed 'Functions.mytimer' (Failed, Id=fc680c7a-cd73-4d7c-9976-ed3facc8c591, Duration=11ms)
[2024-06-05T07:18:09.179Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.mytimer. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: Exception: This is a retryable exception
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 545, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 826, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\v-iafrin\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\functionApp\78578594\function_app.py", line 19, in mytimer
    raise Exception("This is a retryable exception")
.
[2024-06-05T07:18:10.179Z] Executing 'Functions.mytimer' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-06-05T12:48:10.1797346+05:30', Id=032731bb-1b08-40f9-a9c9-71c6c759c478)
[2024-06-05T07:18:10.185Z] Current retry count: 2
[2024-06-05T07:18:10.187Z] Executed 'Functions.mytimer' (Failed, Id=032731bb-1b08-40f9-a9c9-71c6c759c478, Duration=7ms)
[2024-06-05T07:18:10.188Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.mytimer. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: Exception: This is a retryable exception
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 545, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 826, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\*****\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\functionApp\78578594\function_app.py", line 19, in mytimer
    raise Exception("This is a retryable exception")
.
[2024-06-05T07:18:11.195Z] Executing 'Functions.mytimer' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-06-05T12:48:11.1950786+05:30', Id=c365ae71-280b-4fc8-9954-0c6eecd917ce)
[2024-06-05T07:18:11.203Z] Current retry count: 3
[2024-06-05T07:18:11.204Z] Max retries of 3 for function mytimer has been reached
[2024-06-05T07:18:11.214Z] Executed 'Functions.mytimer' (Succeeded, Id=c365ae71-280b-4fc8-9954-0c6eecd917ce, Duration=18ms)


I am still getting the same error.
I am using docker and poetry to add packages. Then exec docker container; poetry shell and ran func host start --python.
I used your host.json file and localsettings.json too.

Can you share screenshot of your folder structure and also share steps you are following to run and create the function

I have edited the question and added folder structure and steps

I can't see requirements.txt file in your folder. It is mandatory that all the packages related to function should be added in requirements.txt file.

I have poetry lock file which has azure function 1.19.0

You need to add the packages being used in Azure function in requirements.txt file. Refer the official doc for V2 function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#folder-structure, you can see the optional and mandatory files for a function to run. Create requirements.txt file and add the function package in it. Your function will work as expected.
